# How can i get a variable declared in method DoInBackground?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Here is My code :

```
         class OpenERP extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Integer>
               @Override
                    protected Integer doInBackground(Context ... params) {

                   try{

                    final Integer id = (Integer) models.execute("execute_kw", asList(
                            db, uid, password,
                            "pointage.task", "create",
                            asList(new HashMap() {
                                {
                                    put("name", "Hello");
                                }


                            })
                    ));}
                  catch (XmlRpcException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Xml Rpc Excception " + e.getMessage());
                }

            return id;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer id) {
            hello.setText(id);

        }
        }
```

I want to get the variable id to use later in my code .
I get the error : can't resolve symbil id !!
coz it's declared inside the bloc try {} .
wht to do ??!

Answer (score 0):

Pass the variable `onPostExecute`.

Change signature of `Async Task` like this:

`class OpenERP extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Integer>`

return `id` in `doInBackground`:

```
protected Integer doInBackground(Context... params) {
    ....
    return id;
}
```

Then override `onPostExecute`

```
protected void onPostExecute(Integer id) {
     // use id here.
}
```

EDIT 1:

Based on comments, this is how you should use it.

```
protected Integer doInBackground(Context ... params) {
               Integer id = Integer.valueOf(0);
               try{

               id = (Integer) models.execute("execute_kw", asList(
                        db, uid, password,
                        "pointage.task", "create",
                        asList(new HashMap() {
                            {
                                put("name", "Hello");
                            }


                        })
                ));}
              catch (XmlRpcException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Xml Rpc Excception " + e.getMessage());
            }

        return id;
}
```

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Yes , I guess it's like tht , but the variable id is declared inside the bloc try{  },so when i put return id , i get : can't resolve varaiable id !! @RohitArya

Comment: If you are able to `return` it in `doInBackground` then you can use it. Update full code if you don't know how to do that.

Comment: i update my code @RohitArya , how can i change it , so i can use the variable id ???

Comment: @Steven7, If my answer helped you in solving the problem, can you upvote and accept my answer?

Comment: Nope my friend , i keep getting this error while trying to show my variable id  : com.example.asus.test_pointage.Authentification$1OpenERP.onPostExecute : it point to : @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Integer id) {
    super.onPostExecute(id);
    TextView a ;
    a=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
  ====>  a.setText(id);


   }

Comment: The cause of this error is something else... If possible, can you add full error log in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as a class variable instead of declaring it in method. In this case declare it as a member of OpenERP class.

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare as global variable and initialize locally.

```
int id;
@Override
protected int doInBackground(Context...params){
  id = /** your desired code*/
  return id;
}
```

Or you may change the parameters in async task as

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, int>
```

which allows you to make you doInBackground return `int` value to catch that in onPostExecute.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(int result){
//access result ass your int value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class OpenERP extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void> {
     private ERPListener mListener;
     public OpenERP(ERPListener listener){
          this.mListener = listener;
     }
     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(Context... params) {

               .....

     final Integer id = ...
     mListener.onCompleted(id);

     return null;
     }
}
```

where

```
public interface ERPListener{
   public void onCompleted(int id);
}
```

When you create the async task, you provide a listener that will be executed when the task completes. It provides the id you need to the calling thread.

Answer (score -1):

Change the return type of doInBackground to int and return your integer value inside doInBackground and you can always get it as int in onPostExecute. Example below,

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```